# What Express websocket events exist?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, websocket

I am wondering what websocket events exist So far I have only been using the `ws.on('message')` event, but I would like to use an event that is triggered when the connection is established and closed. I tried adding `ws.on('connection')`, but that didn't get triggered.

My code:

```
app.ws('/', function (ws, req) {
    ws.on('message', function (textChunk) {
            //do stuff
        }
    });
});
```

Do I need some client side programming to do this?

I tried adding this, but it didn't trigger when I connected from my client.

```
ws.on('request', function () {
  console.log("request");
});
```

Comment: I think you need to do some Google work.  Everything is out there for you to find, including the [detailed specification](https://w3c.github.io/websockets/#the-websocket-interface).  I find [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) a useful starting point for webSocket stuff.  As for the node.js documentation, it is often not very complete.  I regularly have to rely on other sources of information.

Comment: I think you need to handle ws.on("request"). The express-ws library intercepts the connection event and raises another event.

Comment: jfriend00 I read through the documentation, but I am not sure what to make of it... I don't mind reading but do you have anything more specific?

Comment: Please change the title of this question to be completely clear that this question is about ExpressWS (not websockets in general)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After looking at the source code for `express-ws` it looks like you can do the following.

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var expressWs = require('express-ws')(app);

// get the WebsocketServer instance with getWss()
// https://github.com/HenningM/express-ws/blob/5b5cf93bb378a0e6dbe6ab33313bb442b0c25868/index.js#L72-L74
expressWs.getWss().on('connection', function(ws) {
  console.log('connection open');
});

// ... express middleware

// ... websocket middle ware
app.ws('/', function(ws, req) {
  ws.on('message', function(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
  });
});

app.listen(3000);
```

---

### Old Response

There are the following:

```
close
error
message
open
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket#Attributes

Comment: ws.on('open', function() {
  console.log("open");
 });   This didn't trigger when I added it into the code. Why?

Comment: After looking at the code for in express-ws it looks like it handles connections on its own. https://github.com/HenningM/express-ws/blob/master/index.js#L36-L52 I have updated my response.

Comment: It says getWss and ws are undefined :/

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your code completely, are you doing ``var expressWs = require('express-ws')(app);`` in the same file as your ``app.ws()``?

Comment: If you are doing what I said above and still don't have access to getWss() then you might be on an older version. https://github.com/HenningM/express-ws/commit/53a95b821d848ce8a7140127175b0271c6baadbb

Comment: What do you know, I had an old version. ""express-ws": "^0.2.6"," I wonder how that happened. Thank you so much! I'd give you more rep if I could.

Answer (score 11):

The function provided to `app.ws` is the one executed when a new websocket is opened. So use it this way:

```
app.ws('/', function (ws, req) {

    console.log("New connection has opened!");

    ws.on('close', function() {
        console.log('The connection was closed!');
    });

    ws.on('message', function (message) {
        console.log('Message received: '+message);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found one more event that actually triggers. Now if only I would find one that gets called once on open connection.

```
app.ws('/', function (ws, req) {

    ws.on('close', function() {
        console.log('close connection');
    });

    ws.on('message', function (textChunk) {
            //do stuff
        }
    });
});
```